# Percentage based question.

Tags: percentages

In an examination, Mohit obtained $20\%$ more than Sushant but $10\%$ less than Rajesh. If the marks obtained by Sushant is $1080$, find the percentage marks obtained by Rajesh if the full marks is $2000.$

(a) $86.66\%$

(b) $72\%$

(c) $78.33\%$

(d) $77.77\%$

Comment: simple markup and margin.

Answer (score 1):

M = 120% S

M = 90% R

M : S = 6 : 5

M : R = 9 : 10

M : S : R = 18 : 15 : 20

ATQ

15-----> 1080

So, 20 -----> 1080*20/15 = 1440

Now,
1440/2000 * 100 = 72%

Answer (score 0):

[image]

solution is in image. Please let me know if not clear.

Comment: Your answer is correct. You can do it more efficiently as follows. You are given that $M = 1.2S = 0.9R$, and $S = 1080$. You want $R$. No need to solve for $M$. You can simply compute $R = (1.2 / 0.9) S = (4/3) S = (4/3) 1080 = 1440$, or in percentage terms, $1440/2000 = 72\%$.

Comment: I suggest in the future that you simply include your solution in your question, as opposed to posting it as an answer. Welcome to MSE!

Comment: @Bungo. Thanks so much for this precise answer. I just elaborated the answer.

Comment: @HHuang. sure from next i do.